# How to iterate through an intersection properly

Tags: python, loops, set-intersection

I am trying to iterate through a series of intersections, where each iteration is the intersection of a new set of rows. I have code that looks somewhat like the following:

```
    for liness in range(len(NNCatelogue)):
        for iii in [iii for iii, y in enumerate(NNCatelogue[iii]) if y in set(NNCatelogue[liness]).intersection(catid)]:
            print iii, y
```

NNCatelogue is essentially a 1268 X 12 matrix, and each new iteration of liness calls a new row. If I simply put in the row number that I want (ie: 0, 1, 2...) then I get the expected output (without the for loop in front). The code that is written above gives the following output:

```
    10 C-18-1064
    4 C-18-1122
    4 C-18-1122
    5 C-18-1122
    5 C-18-1122
    7 C-18-1122
    8 C-18-1122
    9 C-18-1122
    10 C-18-1122
    11 C-18-1122
    6 C-18-1122
    ...
```

The expected output should be:

```
  0 C-18-1
  1 C-18-259
  2 C-18-303
  3 C-18-304
  4 C-18-309
  5 C-18-324
  6 C-18-335
  7 C-18-351
  8 C-18-372
  9 C-18-373
  10 C-18-518
  11 C-18-8
```

Any idea where I might be going wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:

I tried a variation of one of the answers, and while it is closer to what I am expecting, it isn't quite there. Here is what I tried:

```
    counter = 0
    for row in NNCatelogue:
        for value in row:
            if value in set(NNCatelogue[counter]).intersection(catid):
                print counter, value
                counter += 1
```

The resultant output is:

```
    0 C-18-1
    1 C-18-324
    2 C-18-351
    3 C-18-4
    4 C-18-5
    5 C-18-6
    6 C-18-7
    7 C-18-8
    8 C-18-9
    9 C-18-10
    10 C-18-11
    11 C-18-12
    12 C-18-13
    ...
```

So some of the intersections are correct, though it isn't my desired output... Any ideas from here?

Comment: This is fishy.  You're using `iii` as the looping variable for 2 loops simultaneously. (one is a for loop, the other is a list-comp).

Comment: @JoranBeasley -- But that doesn't really matter.  OP isn't iterating over a set -- just using it to check if an element has been inserted or not...

Comment: I cant tell ... It looks like he's posting because its not ordered how he expects...

Comment: The order doesn't really matter, I'm just not getting the expected output. I do know that there should be 12 outputs for every iteration though.

Comment: I updated the question above. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem yet?

Answer (score 5):

You use `iii` too often. I cannot even imagine what's exactly going on if you execute this code. Just give your variables useful speaking names and your problem is probably solved.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand what you need:

```
counter = 0
for row in NNCatelogue:
    for value in row:
        if value in catid:
            print counter, value
            counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the intersection offers a non-numeric sort... Do you get the proper set (just the wrong permutation)?

Comment: sets are unordered by definition